# How to test default argument called by a mocked method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mocking, python-unittest, assertion

*main.py*

```
def sendContent(path = config.path):
    contentData = content.extractData(path)
    jsonContent = json.dumps(contentData, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
    logging.info("Creating json...")
    return config.createContent(jsonContent)
```

I want to test attributes called by this method. For this, I have to mock method. However, I probably didn't understand how to do because, if I don't specify the attribute in my mock, it doesn't use default parameter (config.path).

Here (one of) my (many) test :

*tests/testMain.py*

```
def testSendContent():
    main.sendContent = Mock()
    main.sendContent()
    main.sendContent.assert_called_with(config.path)
```

**AssertionError: expected call not found**

If, line 3, I put main.sendContent(config.path), the test is OK of course... but if I don't put anything, mock doesn't use default parameter.

Thank you for your help

Comment: `sendContent` is the object under test (OUT). You don't mock the OUT; you mock the things *used* by the OUT, if they have side effects that you don't want to deal with.

Comment: Your test doesn't do much: you're just confirming that Python default arguments work as advertised. A better test would be to check that `main.sendContent()` and `main.sendContent(config.path)` have the same result.

Comment: `assert_called_with` wouldn't detect the use of the default argument anyway. It checks what is actually *passed* to the function call, not what value is ultimately assigned to the parameter. You can verify this with something like `m = Mock(wraps=lambda x=3: x); m(); m.assert_called_with(3)`, as the assertion will fail.

Answer (score 0):

This mock method call main.sendContent() on the second line of 'testSendContent' is not the real call of your sendContent function, it is just a replacement mock function call. Since it is called with no arguments, not with the real function's default ones as you expected.

So instead of checking it with assert_called_with, you can just use your mock call fit for purpose:

1. If you want to bypass the function call of sendContent within the test process
   you can continue with mocking it with specifying the expected return value like
   this:
   main.sendContent = Mock(return_value = "SOME_PATH_HERE")
2. Alternatively, if you want to test sendContent only, don't use mock. Just call it and use :
   self.assertEqual(sendContent(), "SOME_PATH")